# WordPress blog layout to post fullwidth then grid

Tags: php, css, wordpress, layout, blogs

I want to do something a little different with my blog layout, I have seen it done before on WordPress so I know it can be done. Here is what I would like to achieve:

I want my blog to display 5 posts normally, then the older posts to display as a grid bellow. I have made a really quick demo in PS to show you what I mean.
Here is my mock up: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXNtK.jpg

Heres a website I have seen it on:
http://www.speedhunters.com

Here is where I want this to happen:
http://www.motorhive.net

So now you know what I want to do, how do I do it? :D

Comment: In your post loop, just add a counter, which increments, then for every post less than 5, add a different class, then you can style the first 5 posts differently.

Comment: @NickR Would you be willing to give me more information with this? PHP isn't my strong point.

Comment: Sure - my example works with the TwentyTwelve default theme, but you should be able to use it in any theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the TwentyTwelve theme for this example:

**index.php**

Above the `while` loop, you will need to initialise a counter:

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
```

Inside your `while` loop for getting the posts, you can do something like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php 

        if ($count < 1) { 
            $setClass = "less-than";
        } else {
            $setClass = "more-than";
        }

        $count++;

    //  get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
        include(locate_template('content.php'));
    ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This means any post less than 1, since we started the counter at 0, this will only apply it to our first post.

```
if ($count < 1) {
```

You also need to comment out the `get_template_part` function, because we won't have access to our `setClass` variable, instead it will just include the `content.php` page.

**content.php**

Now we can pass the `$setClass` variable, in to `post_class()` function.

So:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Becomes

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($setClass); ?>>
```

So now when you view the index page you won't notice any visual changes, but if you inspect each post, you should see the `class` added to them:

```
<article id="post-4" class="post-4 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry less-than">
```

The `less-than` class is added to this post.

Now you can style up the posts based on those 2 `classes`.

```
.less-than { /* your-styles */ }
.more-than { }
```

**For the Divi theme:**

in `index.php`, use this for your `if` statement:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :

$count = 0;

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
    if ($count < 1) { 
        $setClass = "less-than";
    } else {
        $setClass = "more-than";
    }
    ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'et_pb_post' . ' ' . $setClass ); ?>>

<?php

    $count++;
    echo $count;

    $thumb = '';

    $width = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_width', 1080 );

    $height = (int) apply_filters( 'et_pb_index_blog_image_height', 9999 );
    $classtext = 'et_pb_post_main_image';
    $titletext = get_the_title();
    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, $classtext, $titletext, $titletext, false, 'Blogimage' );
    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

    if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_thumbnails_index', 'on' ) && '' !== $thumb ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height ); ?>
        </a>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Nick

Comment: Still trying to get this working. I do not have a content.php, What do I do with the code you have me for that file?

Comment: @LukeD1uk Which theme are you using? You should have an `index.php` file which pulls in the posts on the home/blog page.

Comment: I am using Divi, made by Elegant Themes. I have an index.php that's fine, but no content.php . Not sure what to do.. Maybe you could have a look yourself?

Comment: @LukeD1uk - I've had a look at the theme - it should be a little easier with this theme, since all the post loop stuff happens in `index.php`. I've added that to the answer, so hopefully that should work for you. You might want to remove `echo $count;` - it's just there for debugging purposes - so you can see it's echoing the correct number.

Comment: Thanks again for a brilliant reply! I added your code into my `index.php` but still the classes are not being applied to my articles. Any idea what I am doing wrong, Thank you Nick :D

Comment: I have just noticed this is actually working, but only on tag pages. any-more help for this one Nick? 
http://motorhive.net/tag/drift/ I styled `less-than` 5 red, and `more-than` 5 blue.

Comment: Also works on categories. This leads me to believe that this would work if the home page was latest posts, not using the template.